# socket lagging every few seconds

Tags: python, sockets, pygame

i am beginner with the network programming actually this is my first networking code ever ,

my problem is i was trying to make simple online game but the game keep lagging its not lagging when i open the server code and the client code on the same computer

but when i open the client code on different  computer it start to lagging 
it work very great for few seconds then suddenly it stop working for like one or two seconds or less , then it come back working again with no problems,

after trying to found out where the lagging happen it was looking like it happen on both the server and the client in the same time and they come back working also on the same time

after searching for solution for while i didn't found anything working for me as long as most of the solutions i found was for more advance problems but i found that i should use "PodSixNet" for online games not socket but i am still going to try with the socket , here is my code :

the server :

```
import socket,pygame,os,sys 
from pygame.locals import*
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (0,30)
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
serverSocket.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 23000)) 
serverSocket.listen(1)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((250,250))
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WHITE = (250, 250, 250)
x=0
y=0
chx=0
chy=0
while True:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT :
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        clientSocket, (remoteHost, remotePort) = serverSocket.accept()
        rec = clientSocket.recv(100)
        clientSocket.close()
        chx=rec[0]
        chy=rec[1] 
        if rec[0]==2:
                chx=-1
        if rec[1]==2:
                chy=-1
        x+=chx
        y+=chy 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (x,y,10,10))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick_busy_loop(60)
```

the client :

```
import socket,pygame
from pygame.locals import*
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((250,250))
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
WHITE = (250, 250, 250)
chx=0
chy=0
x=0
y=0
chxx=0
chyy=0
while True:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT :
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==K_w:
                        chy=2
                    if event.key==K_d: 
                        chx=1
                    if event.key==K_s:
                        chy=1
                    if event.key==K_a:
                        chx=2
            if event.type==KEYUP:
                    if event.key==K_w or event.key==K_s:
                        chy=0
                    if event.key==K_d or event.key==K_a:
                        chx=0
        clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        clientSocket.connect(('192.168.0.112', 23000))
        clientSocket.send(bytearray([chx,chy]))
        clientSocket.close()
        chxx=chx
        chyy=chy
        if chx==2:
                chxx=-1
        if chy==2:
                chyy=-1
        x+=chxx
        y+=chyy
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (x,y,10,10))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick_busy_loop(60)
```

and i know there is lot of lazy and wrong things on that code its because this is not the code i will use in the game ,

in that code iam just trying to make the online working with out lagging

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're opening and closing the socket with every loop iteration.

Try opening the socket before the loop and then closing it when the loop exits.

Comment: thank you so so much sir yes that was my problem now its working great